# how to push the each loop variable value in to the array

Tags: javascript, ajax

My problem is how do push each loop variable value in to the single array?(my code is not working)

```
$(document).on('click', '.overtime_check', function() {
   //temp = 0;

  $('#ot_send_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {
    var test = [];
    var emp_no = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var ot_hours = $(tr).find('input').val();
    test.push(ot_hours);

    });
        $.ajax({
              url: 'ot_divide_action.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: { action:'check_ot_count', test:test},
              //dataType:"json",
              success:function(data)
              {
              //swal({title: "No data entering?",text: "Not set the overtime hours !",type: "warning"});
              $('#display-output').html(data);
             }
          });
   //swal({title: "No data entering?",text: "Not set the overtime hours !",type: "warning"});

});
```

i want to sent below format of array through ajax request

```
$time_arr =  [
'00:02:55',
'00:07:56',
'01:03:32',
'15:13:34',
'02:13:44',
'03:08:53',
'13:13:54'
 ];
```

how do i do it ?

**update Code**

Comment: First you iterate, *then* you send the ajax request. You don't put the ajax request inside the loop.

Comment: You need to make the variable global, declare it outside the each scope.

Comment: what variable should define in globaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you define the `var test = [];` array inside the `.each()` callback. You need to define it *before* the iteration. Try this one:

```
$(document).on('click', '.overtime_check', function() {
    //temp = 0;

    var test = []; // Here, the array declaration should be outside the each()

    $('#ot_send_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {
        var emp_no = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var ot_hours = $(tr).find('input').val();
        test.push(ot_hours);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ot_divide_action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { action:'check_ot_count', test:test},
        //dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            //swal({title: "No data entering?",text: "Not set the overtime hours !",type: "warning"});
            $('#display-output').html(data);
        }
    });
    //swal({title: "No data entering?",text: "Not set the overtime hours !",type: "warning"});
});
```